# Can one create multiple exposure images with a Canon DSLR?

Tags: canon, multiple-exposure

In looking at the user manual for a Nikon D7000, I see that the camera can create [multiple exposure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_exposure) images (where more than one image is exposed into the same frame) in-camera.  I don't recall ever hearing that was possible with my previous DSLRs (which have all been Canon).

Do any Canon DSLRs offer the ability to do multiple exposures?

Comment: Seriously, just use photoshop :)

Comment: I'm betting the D7000 is doing it in software anyway; it would be silly to keep the sensor charged while the shutter is closed -- you'd just increase noise and waste power.

Comment: I would post this as an answer, but for some reason this question is locked. This is an old post, and some of the answers are obsolete.  The Canon 70D, introduced in 2013, has a rather complete multiple-exposure feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: **no**. Longer answer: **You can fake it, to a degree, with long exposures.**

In a nutshell, what you want to do start your exposure, expose the first part, then cover the lens with a dark cloth, reposition, and remove it to expose again.

It’s not as precise, it’s more work, it works better at night, and it might not be worth it. That said, you can get some neat effects with the technique:
[image: Example]
(via [dreamsjung](http://www.flickr.com/photos/dreamsjung/))

Answer (score 5):

I cannot speak personally for *all* models of Canon EOS cameras, but I do know that it's specifically not possible with the following Canon models:

- 1DmkIV
- 5DmkII
- 7D
- 50D
- 40D
- 20D

Based on this pattern it'd be pretty easy to infer that the rest of the EOS line (and possibly other Canon lines as well) does not have this functionality. That is to say that it's 'not possible' in-camera without 'faking it' as outlined in @ieure's [answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8925/can-one-create-multiple-exposure-images-with-a-canon-dslr/8934#8934). Obviously with the use of post-processing it's fully possible to make double (or triple, or more...) exposures. Also (probably obviously) it's *completely possible* with any of the bodies in the EOS film camera lineup... But I know that's not what you're asking about... Just trying to be complete. ;-)

Comment: The EOS 5D Mark III does do multiple exposures, with different styles of overlaying.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are [currently 30 cameras supporting multiple-exposures](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?multipleexposure=1) and [3 of them are from Canon](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?multipleexposure=1&brand=canon).

Most models optionally adjust the gain to prevent multiple correctly exposed images to be combined into an over-exposed one. Fuji has a nice implementation where you can undo the last exposure and re-take it as often as you need to get it right.

Comment: Do you have a link to the list of the 23 cameras that can?

Comment: @ahockley - Sorry not this time. I had to query my database (http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php) internally for that. I didn't put options for everything but most common (even even some less common) queries can be done there.

Comment: @ahockley - There is not an external way to query this, so I can provide direct links to results.

Answer (score 3):

The newer [EOS 5D Mark III](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/slr_cameras/eos_5d_mark_iii?selectedName=Features&fileName=0901e0248045f5aa_feature9.html) also has multiple exposures.

Answer (score 1):

Everything I've read says you can't. Here's a few articles I found from researching.

http://forums.steves-digicams.com/canon-eos-dslr/136216-multiple-exposures.html

http://photo.net/canon-eos-digital-camera-forum/004YCQ

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080820092042AA3hfY2

This last article is interesting, if you really want to do a multiple exposure image.

http://www.msjphotography.com/index.php/2010/07/photoshop-workbench-236-canon-multiple-exposure-script/

Answer (score 1):

From [Canon October 2011 release](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/about_canon?pageKeyCode=pressreldetail&docId=0901e024803b812e)

"The EOS-1D X is the first EOS Digital SLR to feature Multiple Exposure capability. The camera can combine up to nine individual images into a single composite image…"

Comment: It would be better if you combined your two answers.  Ideally any question should have a single comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Canon cameras that can shoot multi exposures:

- EOS-1D X
- EOS 5D Mark III
- EOS 6D

Complete list: [Canon models that are capable of shooting multiple exposures](http://www.canon.co.uk/Support/Consumer_Products/products/cameras/Digital_SLR/EOS_1100D.aspx?faqtcmuri=tcm:14-915154&page=1&type=faq)

Answer (score 0):

Fake it in Photoshop.

[image: Fake Multiple Exposure with Photoshop, a tripod, and layers]
To get this shot I tripod mounted and took lots of photos during the parade. I then picked the ones I wanted ghosted, and brought them into photoshop, carefully pixel aligned them, and then played with the transparency slider on each layer.

Answer (score -3):

In regard to the comment about it being impossible for the 40D to take a double exposure...that is not true in my experience.

I took a very cool double exposure (coincidentally by mistake) of a painting I had done and of an old wooden floor and the picture came out awesome. In fact, I began to do several other cool shots likewise. So it is very much possible to take double exposures with the 40D and I bet with the Xsi as well.

Come to think of it, I have done it with the Xsi using lights as my subjects.

In a nutshell...it can be done totally in camera and without any need of software.

Comment: Can you explain how it's done? There seems to be a lot of information saying it's impossible, so if you've got the way, I'm sure a lot of people would like to know.

Comment: I'm sure the shutter speed was slow but what I would rather do I'd find the picture and it's properties and post them later. Keep n mind, I did these pix accidentally. I was just experimenting with the camera. However, I kid you not, it can b done.