# Can I take multiple exposure shots with my Canon 600D?

Tags: canon, exposure, canon-600d, multiple-exposure

Can I take multiple exposure shots with my 600D? If not, how I can achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 3):

It is **not** possible with your 600D. You have to use additional post-processing software like Photoshop, Gimp or something else.

Please see here: http://support-au.canon.com.au/contents/AU/EN/8201440300.html

and here: [Can one create multiple exposure images with a Canon DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8925/can-one-create-multiple-exposure-images-with-a-canon-dslr)